# MySQL auto delete in 24 hours

Tags: mysql

I have a table with name of del_rows. I have set columns like id, description and duration in my table. The id type is INT, description LONGTEXT and the duration is TIMESTAMP.

I inserted some values to my table. Now the duration value is 2012-03-17 22:48:27. I want to delete this row in 24 hours. I am using WAMP server on Windows XP.

What to do to delete the entire row in 24 hours?

Comment: Do it manually? Setting up a scheduled task to run to delete one row seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cron Jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). It is very simple to work with Cron so your machine can be easily configured to run repetitive tasks.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on this?  Would you schedule a cron job for each row?  Or run it every hour (minute, day?) to clean out rows that should be expired now?

Comment: write a query that deletes based on the timestamp. Write a script that executes that query. Set a cron to call that script. every x times (depending on how precise you need them to be deleted..

Comment: hi, how to run cron job in wamp server on windows xp? iam quite new to php and mysql.

Comment: Cron jobs isnt available for Windows but You could use scheduled tasks in Windows - http://drupal.org/node/31506 or you could use http://cronw.sourceforge.net/ which is set of PERL enabled CRON style tools for Windows.

Comment: Hi, i am trying to set php script with windows sheduled task. so, I need to set php.exe file to execute the script.How to find php.exe file in the wamp server 2.o version.